# Rendering bug in Google Chrome at certain window widths

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, tooltip

My users and I are running into a rendering glitch in Chrome only (on both Windows and Mac) where an overlaid div that I'm using for on-hover tooltip-style "popouts"(see first image below) does not get rendered properly in certain cases (see second image below). In all other browsers I've tested, it works as expected.

**Here's how the hover popouts are supposed to look (and what happens in Firefox, Safari, IE):**

[image: Safari: Good]

**Here's what happens in Chrome:**

[image: Chrome: Bad]

You can see it in action on [this site](http://demo.nutrislice.com/menu/meadow-creek/lunch/) if you look at May 24 using a browser window width of ~ 1200px (significnatly wider or narrower windows do not seem to work).  The glitch only affects the popouts in the bottom right of the menu that are popping left, e.g. those on May 24. Hovers using the same exact mechanism higher up in the page work just fine. Glitched popouts are invisible (except for part of the carat), but if you click on the link to lock the popout in place and then hold left click while moving your mouse around as if to "select text" in the area where the popout should be, it will then render partially. Also if I open dev tools and try to select the popout, it will render just fine at that point.

I've been looking at this all day and trying different work arounds with opacity, z-index, etc. and getting nowhere. *Does this glitch ring any bells for anyone? Is there a way to force Chrome to render the div, once its been positioned and unhidden?* I'm fine with any work-around or hack.

I use a custom (and fairly complicated) jquery plugin for popouts.  If it would be helpful to see the non-minified javascript for the plugin, I can post or provide a link to that, but general guidance that leads me to a work around will be sufficient to be accepted as an answer.

Edit: My Browser Build: 26.0.1410.65

Comment: On line 883 inside https://nutrislice-menus.s3.amazonaws.com/css/menu.css?v=2.4.5 there is a overflow: hidden which might cause the problem. Edit: Never mind, it worked removing it the first time, but not after reload.

Comment: To those of you with an itchy "close" trigger finger... consider that although this question may seem quite specific to my build, that its apparently a browser bug in need of a work around which may be useful to others as well ... (unless its a duplicate, then by all means point me in the right direction and I'll close myself).  Please be compassionate and if you feel its borderline, let it slide.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on chrome on mac 26.0

Comment: Same here, can't reproduce on Mac Chrome 26.0.1410.65

Comment: @DavidNguyen  That's the same build I use.  Its not always consistent, but if you shrinking or expanding your browser window width and test the bottom right hovers (e.g. May 24th), you may see it?  (I've seen it on 2 different macs and Windows 7 at this point). Regardless, thanks for checking it out.

Comment: @limelights Another link I'm seeing it at: http://dcsd.nutrislice.com/menu/cherokee-trail/lunch/  . Its only the bottom right hovers (e.g. on the 24th and only shows up at certain browser widths (not too small, not too big)

Comment: Can't reproduce on chrome 26 on windows.

Comment: @BenRoberts that works as well

Comment: @limelights thanks for checking it out.  I see it show up at 1200px browser width, but sometimes it doesn't when the browser window significantly less or more. Hopefully others can reproduce. Regardless, good to know that not every chrome user is affected.

Comment: I can reproduce on Chrome 26 after repeated resizing and trying multiple links. And it *does* appear to be a bug, because if I select part of the phantom contents of the box, those parts show up, meaning there is nothing inherently wrong with the layout (like bad z-index or zero height).

Comment: BTW, throw a CSS transform onto the element and see if that does anything...transforms (especially 3D-related) can change the drawing process (this is often used to trigger hardware acceleration).

Comment: Try `-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);` I edited the style inline for one popup which was consistently exhibiting the behavior, and this fixed it. Then I added it to the whole document, and it fixed all the errors I was seeing.

Comment: @TimMedora Awesome! That works.  Feel free to add as an answer if you like reputation points. Regardless, you're a life saver, my wife will thank you as well.

Comment: Great! I just wrote it up. It's too bad this is so hard to reproduce; it seems like a genuine (and serious) rendering bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>(Per my comments)</sup>

This does indeed seem to be a bug in Chrome, though without a smaller test case to reproduce it, it could be very hard to track down. You may want to report it to the Chrome team with as much information as possible.

In support of my "it's a bug" assertion:

- The hidden/clipped elements become visible when they are selected.
- The elements underneath the hidden/clipped elements are not clickable.
- This indicates that `z-index` and height is correct.
- It only happens under very specific circumstances; the rest of the items with the same style work fine. The *same* item may work fine at a slightly bigger/smaller screen width.
- Applying a 3D transform fixes it.

The problem goes away when I apply a CSS transform such as `scale3d` or `translate3d`. I imagine this is because [certain CSS properties cause the browser to switch to GPU acceleration](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css).

In this case, [switching to the fast path for rendering](http://peter.sh/2010/06/chromium-now-features-gpu-acceleration-and-css-3d-transforms/) seems to alter the drawing sequence enough to fix the problem.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to Chrome team, but as you say... it may be hard to track down, since we just happened to create the circumstances to trigger the bug and who knows what specifically sets it off.

Answer (score 1):

Super hacky but this fixes it for me:

```
$('.drop-link.food').on('hover',function() {
  $('.tool-tip').css('overflow', 'hidden').height();
  $('.tool-tip').css('overflow', 'auto');
});
```

Obviously this isn't a "good" solution, and even remaining hacky you could probably optimize it to only force the redraw on the tooltip it needs to, but hopefully it helps...

Another clue:

```
$('.drop-link').on('hover',function() {
  $(this).siblings('.tool-tip').css('display','block');
});
```

This won't fix it right away, but it seems like if this is there, once you've hovered on something, it will work the next time you hover on it.

Comment: Just noticed it puts scrollbars on and hides the arrow, but it makes it show up at least.  So maybe not a perfect solution but hopefully gives you something to work with.

Comment: Yeah. Not perfect buy may provide a clue. Any idea what the underlying problem is? Maybe I can restructure the hover to avoid it. It seems that some weirdness with the arrow might have freaked chrome out.

Comment: Can't be sure, but it seems like for some reason, chrome isn't triggering a redraw when it gets set to display.  Or it triggers the redraw but thinks the elements width is 0 or something and so the overflow: hidden is hiding it.

Comment: Thanks for spending some time on this... looks like Tim found a relatively clean css workaround.  I'm really grateful right now, I'm sure you've been there too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps with your situation, but over the last couple of days I've started to notice that certain site elements on Facebook and Weight Watchers no longer show up. Specifically it seems to be affecting items that (I believe) to be controlled by or dependent on Javascript. When I call up these sites in Firefox and Safari they work as expected.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Yeah these types of tooltip popups are very javascript-intensive but its hard to really come to any conclusions off of that.